Why is my JEST mockResolvedValueOnce not working?
I have this function:
export const insertOne = async (table, data) => {
  try {
    const client = await getClient();
    const db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DATABASE);
    const collection = db.collection(table);
    const { insertedId } = await collection.insertOne({
      ...data,
      createdAt: moment().tz("America/Mexico_City").toISOString(),
      updatedAt: moment().tz("America/Mexico_City").toISOString(),
    });
    const insertedData = await collection.findOne({ _id: insertedId });
    return insertedData;
  } catch (error) {
    mwLogger('error', 'Error inserting one to the database :', {
      name: error?.name || 'Unknown Error',
      message: error?.message || 'No message provided',    
      code: error?.code || 'No error code',  
      stack: error?.stack || 'No stack trace available' 
    });
    throw new Error('Database insertion failed');
  }
}

It works as expected with database connection strings, table and the collection. But When I try to do a JEST Test of it I have one issue. This is my test file so I can clarify:
describe('insertOne', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      // Mock db and collection setup
      mockDb = { collection: jest.fn() };
      mockCollection = { insertOne: jest.fn(), findOne: jest.fn() };
      mockClient = { db: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockDb) };

      // Mock MongoClient.connect to return mockClient
      MongoClient.connect.mockResolvedValue(mockClient);

      // Mock collection method to return mockCollection
      mockDb.collection.mockReturnValue(mockCollection);
    });

    it('should insert data correctly and return the inserted document', async () => {
      const mockData = { name: 'John Doe' };
  
      // Mock the insertOne method to resolve with insertedId
      const insertedId = '123';
      mockCollection.insertOne.mockResolvedValueOnce({ insertedId });
  
      // Mock findOne to return the inserted data with timestamps
      const mockInsertedData = {
        _id: insertedId,
        ...mockData,
        createdAt: expect.any(String),
        updatedAt: expect.any(String),
      };
      mockCollection.findOne.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockInsertedData);
  
      const result = await insertOne('users', mockData);
  
      // Assertions
      expect(mockCollection.insertOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        expect.objectContaining({
          ...mockData,
          createdAt: expect.any(String),
          updatedAt: expect.any(String),
        })
      );
      expect(result).toEqual(mockInsertedData);
    });
  });

The piece of code of the test file mockCollection.insertOne.mockResolvedValueOnce({ insertedId }); is not mocking the result I want out of that test. Which is the await collection.insertOne of the source file.
What would the correct approach be to mock that specific piece of code?
The error im getting is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertedId')

const db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DATABASE)  this isn't treating client.db() as an async function so why are you mocking it as one?

You mean this piece of code? mockClient = { db: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockDb) }; I tried making it synchronous, it gives me the same results. What I'm trying to do is mock the collection so that it returns the values I'm looking for.  mockClient = {  db: jest.fn(() => mockDb) }; What I'm doing is debugging the const { insertedId } checking for a returned value.

D'oh, you're right. I thought it had mockResolvedValue. Ignore my comment

The supposedly-simpler, supposedly-"correct" answer: "don't do it that way".
Here is a document on how to use Jest with MongoDB. Instead of mocking specific things, there is a preset to use @shelf/jest-mongodb.
yarn add --dev @shelf/jest-mongodb

In your jest config:
{
  "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb"
}

Now it'll run a fake client in memory. You can let your code connect to it, and you can just insert fake documents in your tests and let your code query for them. You can even query in your tests to see if your code inserted documents.
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

describe('insert', () => {
  let connection;
  let db;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(globalThis.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    db = await connection.db(globalThis.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
  });

  it('should insert a doc into collection', async () => {
    const users = db.collection('users');

    const mockUser = {_id: 'some-user-id', name: 'John'};
    await users.insertOne(mockUser);

    const insertedUser = await users.findOne({_id: 'some-user-id'});
    expect(insertedUser).toEqual(mockUser);
  });
});


The do-it-yourself way:

Some libraries make it very very difficult to override things (notably the previous version of the aws-sdk library).
If MongoDB ISN'T one of those, and if you really really want to "do it that way":

This code
MongoClient.connect.mockResolvedValue(mockClient);

is mocking a static function on the MongoClient class, and not the connect function on the instances of the client:
class MongoClient {
  // You're mocking this
  static connect() {}

  // not this
  connect() {}
}

